What is the difference between subordinating conjunctions and coordinating conjunctions?
Example to show the problem:
IMHO "but" is similar to although, so that we can modify this example from cambridge dictionary:

Everyone enjoyed the trip to the final although we lost the match!

to:

Everyone enjoyed the trip to the final, but we lost the match!

IMHO both are fine. Maybe here but becomes the subordinating conjunction as the prowritingaid blog says:

But is another coordinating conjunction. Like and, it’s perfectly acceptable to begin a sentence with but. But can also act like a subordinating conjunction.


subordinating conjunctions definition

subordinate clause constructed by subordinating conjunctions is defined as


A subordinate clause is a clause that cannot stand alone as a complete sentence

But "although we lost the match" and "but we lost the match" both can't be one complete sentence which can be said directly in one conversation without any context.

dependent clauses constructed by subordinating conjunctions


dependent clauses change the meaning of independent clauses

But for the above example, the meaning of "Everyone enjoyed the trip to the final" is not changed.
Q:
Then how to differentiate "between subordinating conjunctions and coordinating conjunctions" and show whether the above "but" is one subordinating conjunction or coordinating conjunction?

p.s.
For more example sentences constructed from subordinating conjunctions like if etc (not include but since the only place where but is also considered as the subordinating conjunction is the above prowritingaid blog), see this quillbot blog.

Isn't it incumbent upon you to show us an example and ask if but is being used as a subordinating conjunction there as you think it is?  It is not clear what you mean by  "one transition of speech".

@TimR Thanks. Actually examples help understanding the original problem. I have updated my question with one example and describe the question more detailedly instead of just asking one example. If there are still problems with my question, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

"But we lost the match." is valid as a sentence. It wouldn't make a lot of sense on its own but lots of sentences wouldn't, including this one. Are you claiming it's ungrammatical to start a sentence with but or do you have some other reason for denying that? (You could also look at other questions on subordinating and coordinating conjunctions, like this or this or search individual conjunctions.)

Your although-but pair of sentences is indeed fine, but I’d point out that they differ slightly in meaning. In the although version, the fact of their having enjoyed the trip is the main thought, and the fact of their nonetheless having lost the match is something of an addendum. In the but version, the loss of the match is more the main thought, as illustrated by the fact that that sentence can be paraphrased as Although we enjoyed the trip, we lost the match.

That quillbot thing does not show sentences. So, provide an example of but used as a subordinating conjunction. I doubt you can.

@Lambie Yes. That link only shows examples for normal subordinating conjunctions like "if" etc in "Subordinating conjunctions examples". So I ask whether the above example with but is one example where but is "used as a subordinating conjunction".

@StuartF 1. ""But we lost the match." is valid as a sentence." IMHO if we directly say this with someone without saying others beforehand, it will be weird. So that's why I think this is not one complete sentence. 2. IMHO Your 1st link is about "and" with "which" by showing some  informal/wrong transformations. That doesn't tell the difference between these 2 types of conjunctions. This is same for the 2nd link. But IMHO "nor those of the class struggle" is also not one complete sentence, so why is nor also one "coordinating conjunction"?

There is some sort of mistake there. When you click on the link and go to the other page, there is no example of but used as a subordinating conjunction. And I find no examples anywhere of but as a "subordinating" conjunction.

@Lambie Yes. I have said normal in the above comment which doesn't include but. "but" is said to also be subordinating conjunction in prowritingaid blog seemingly without one example. Sorry for possible ambiguity.

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a mistake in a text from a blog quoted by the OP.

@Lambie What is "a mistake in a text from a blog"? Sorry if I misunderstood your meanings but my question is not based on that quillbot blog which is just shown in p.s. part. And the quillbot blog doesn't have errors as my above comment says. I will clarify that in the question.

"But can also act like a subordinating conjunction."

OP's query on subordinating and coordinating conjunctions:

"Everyone enjoyed the trip to the final  although we lost the match!"
"We lost the match, but everyone enjoyed the trip to the final."

I adjusted the second sentence, as it sounds clearer this way.
Subordinating and Coordinating Conjunctions

**Coordinating Conjunctions/Sentences:*" Coordinating conjunctions (e.g., for, and, nor, but, or, yet, so) link two independent clauses of equal importance, each of which can stand alone as a complete sentence. Coordinating sentences are generally balanced, connecting two equally weighted ideas. For example, in
"We lost the match, but everyone enjoyed the trip to the final,".
both parts can stand alone as independent sentences, linked by the coordinating conjunction  but.

Subordinating Conjunctions/Sentences: Subordinating conjunctions (e.g., although, because, since, if) connect an independent clause with a dependent (subordinate) clause.
A subordinating conjunction creates a relationship where one clause depends on the other to make sense. For example, in.
"Although we lost the match, everyone enjoyed the trip to the final," the clause "Although we lost the match" cannot stand alone and depends on the main clause for its full meaning.


Difference subordinating and coordinating sentences:
We typically avoid starting sentences with coordinating conjunctions, but subordinating conjunctions can easily introduce a sentence. This flexibility is another reason for classifying but as a coordinating conjunction and although as a subordinating conjunction.
For example:

"Although we lost the match, everyone enjoyed the trip to the final."

"But" Followed by a Subordinating Clause:
In these sentences, "but" is followed by a subordinating clause introduced by "when". "But" still acts as a coordinating conjunction, connecting this sentence to a previous idea or sentence. The "when" clause provides a condition or circumstance for the main clause.

Examples:

"But when there is turbulence, it is a lot of work for the pilot."
"But when there is already a widespread loss of confidence, sunlight is the only treatment left."
"But when it comes to behavior, biology cannot mandate."
"But when it comes to landscapes and rooms, it's different.".
.
But when there is.
But when it comes to



Thanks. The last section gives one good explanation of why "but" is considered as "coordinating conjunction" since "But we lost the match, everyone enjoyed the trip to the final." is very weird. I upvoted for you. But as prowritingaid blog says, "but" can be also a subordinating conjunction. Is that right or wrong actually? If right, could you give one example for that and shows the difference between the case where "but" is a subordinating conjunction and the corresponding coordinating case?

@An5Drama I had thought about this. Why the same sentence becomes subordinating when you change the conjunction. Regarding the rule that sentences cannot start with coordinating conjunctions, you will find sentences do start with  but, and. I didn't find anywhere that "but" can be a subordinating conjunction and it is the first time I am hearing it. Maybe it is in cases where "but" is used for reason or maybe a combination of. but for. The blog didn't provide an explanation or an example supporting it.


Maybe you have one typo, i.e. "you won't find sentences do start with but, and." Anyway I understood your answer. Maybe the prowritingaid blog is wrong since "The blog didn't provide an explanation or an example supporting it." 2. Could you give one reference for your last section's "We typically avoid starting sentences with coordinating conjunctions"? That will be better. Anyway It is also fine if without the reference.


@An5Drama I edited and added the information I found regarding "but" followed by a subordinating clause. but" is followed by a subordinating clause introduced by "when". "But" still acts as a coordinating conjunction, connecting this sentence to a previous idea or sentence. The "when" clause provides a condition or circumstance for the main clause.

Thanks. In that case, although can't connect with when. This is one more difference.

@An5Drama Similarly you can find sentences starting with, "But as soon as ".

Your last 2 links share one very useful app although without one iOS version.  Thanks very much.

"But" is used to connect two contrasting ideas within a single sentence. Those ideas are separated by a comma:

Everyone enjoyed the trip to the final, but we lost the match.

This does not mean that you were happy about the loss. It means you enjoyed the trip as a whole. The match loss is presented as a separate statement. In fact, it could mean that you were enjoying it up to the point of the loss. Consider if someone said "I was hopeful that we would win, but then we lost" - you would understand that their hopefulness ended when they lost.
"Although" is used to introduce a subordinate clause that contrasts with the main clause. You don't need a comma - in fact, you can use it before the main clause:


Although we lost, everyone enjoyed the trip to the final.
Everyone enjoyed the trip to the final although we lost the match!


The difference is subtle, but this better suggests that overall, the trip and the match were enjoyable despite the loss. Consider if someone said, "I was feeling hopeful, despite the other team playing so well" - you would understand that your hopefulness was maintained throughout the match, despite the other team playing well.


You answered my 1st question by showing their usage differences. So the above but after comma is coordinating conjunction. Then if we say "Everyone enjoyed the trip to the final but we lost the match!", does that but function as "subordinating conjunction"? If so, what is the difference about their meanings? Is the difference at their emphasis locations as Paul Tanenbaum's comment says? 2. One notice for the future readers: Here despite is one preposition which is followed by one noun.


@An5Drama If the clauses can stand independently on their own then one is not subordinate to the other. In other words, if you could replace "but" with a full stop and it still makes sense (however clunky) then its a coordinating conjunction.

If so, then we can also do that for the although case, which implies although is a coordinating conjunction... Sorry for my possible pedantry.
